# How do I create an HttpContext for my unit test?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-core

I am struggling to simulate the required `HttpContext` for my unit tests.

I have abstracted control of the session away from my Mvc controller with a `SessionManager` interface and implemented this with a class called `CookieSessionManager`. (**early development stages**).

`CookieSessionManager` uses the `HttpContext` by using the injected singleton `HttpContextAccessor` (in Startup.cs ConfigureServices).

I'm using Cookie Authentication which is setup in Startup.cs with `app.UseCookieAuthentication`.

**Testing this manually in debug mode works as expected**

The `MSUnit` tests I have written for my `AccountController` class work with a `MockSessionManager` class injected.

The real issue I have is with the unit tests I have written for my `CookieSessionManager` class. I have tried to setup the `HttpContext` as shown below;

```
[TestClass]
public class CookieSessionManagerTest
{
    private IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor;
    private HttpContext context;
    private SessionManager sessionManager;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Setup_CookieSessionManagerTest()
    {
        context = new DefaultHttpContext();

        contextAccessor = new HttpContextAccessor();

        contextAccessor.HttpContext = context;

        sessionManager = new CookieSessionManager(contextAccessor);
    }
```

**The Error**

But the call to `sessionManager.Login(CreateValidApplicationUser());` doesn't appear to set the `IsAuthenticated` flag and the test `CookieSessionManager_Login_ValidUser_Authenticated_isTrue` fails.

```
[TestMethod]
public void CookieSessionManager_Login_ValidUser_Authenticated_isTrue()
{
    sessionManager.Login(CreateValidApplicationUser());

    Assert.IsTrue(sessionManager.isAuthenticated());
}

public ApplicationUser CreateValidApplicationUser()
{
    ApplicationUser applicationUser = new ApplicationUser();

    applicationUser.UserName = "ValidUser";

    //applicationUser.Password = "ValidPass";

    return applicationUser;
}
```

> Test Name:    CookieSessionManager_Login_ValidUser_Authenticated_isTrue
>
> : line 43 Test Outcome:   Failed Test Duration:   0:00:00.0433169
>
> Result StackTrace:    at ClaimsWebAppTests.Identity.CookieSessionManagerTest.CookieSessionManager_Login_ValidUser_Authenticated_isTrue()
>
> CookieSessionManagerTest.cs:line 46 Result Message:    Assert.IsTrue failed.

**MY CODE**

**SessionManager**

```
using ClaimsWebApp.Models;

namespace ClaimsWebApp.Identity
{
    public interface SessionManager
    {
        bool isAuthenticated();

        void Login(ApplicationUser applicationUser);

        void Logout();
    }
}
```

**CookieSessionManager**

```
using ClaimsWebApp.Identity;
using ClaimsWebApp.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Claims;

namespace ClaimsWebApp
{
    public class CookieSessionManager : SessionManager
    {
        private List<ApplicationUser> applicationUsers;
        private IHttpContextAccessor ContextAccessor;
        private bool IsAuthenticated;

        public CookieSessionManager(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
        {
            this.IsAuthenticated = false;

            this.ContextAccessor = contextAccessor;

            IsAuthenticated = ContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;

            applicationUsers = new List<ApplicationUser>();

            applicationUsers.Add(new ApplicationUser { UserName = "ValidUser" });
        }
        public bool isAuthenticated()
        {
            return IsAuthenticated;
        }

        public void Login(ApplicationUser applicationUser)
        {
            if (applicationUsers.Find(m => m.UserName.Equals(applicationUser.UserName)) != null)
            {
                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, applicationUser.UserName)
                },
                "MyCookieMiddlewareInstance");

                var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

                ContextAccessor.HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync("MyCookieMiddlewareInstance", principal);

                IsAuthenticated = ContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("User not found");
            }
        }

        public void Logout()
        {
            ContextAccessor.HttpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync("MyCookieMiddlewareInstance");

            IsAuthenticated = ContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
        }
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
using ClaimsWebApp.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace ClaimsWebApp
{
    public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
            services.AddScoped<SessionManager, CookieSessionManager>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole();

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                AuthenticationScheme = "MyCookieMiddlewareInstance",
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Unauthorized/"),
                AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Account/Forbidden/"),
                AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
                AutomaticChallenge = true
            });

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Account}/{action=Login}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**CookieSessionManagerTest.cs**

```
using ClaimsWebApp;
using ClaimsWebApp.Identity;
using ClaimsWebApp.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace ClaimsWebAppTests.Identity
{
    [TestClass]
    public class CookieSessionManagerTest
    {
        private IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor;
        private HttpContext context;
        private SessionManager sessionManager;

        [TestInitialize]
        public void Setup_CookieSessionManagerTest()
        {
            context = new DefaultHttpContext();

            contextAccessor = new HttpContextAccessor();

            contextAccessor.HttpContext = context;

            sessionManager = new CookieSessionManager(contextAccessor);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void CookieSessionManager_Can_Be_Implemented()
        {
            Assert.IsInstanceOfType(sessionManager, typeof(SessionManager));
        }


        [TestMethod]
        public void CookieSessionManager_Default_Authenticated_isFalse()
        {
            Assert.IsFalse(sessionManager.isAuthenticated());
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void CookieSessionManager_Login_ValidUser_Authenticated_isTrue()
        {
            sessionManager.Login(CreateValidApplicationUser());

            Assert.IsTrue(sessionManager.isAuthenticated());
        }

        public ApplicationUser CreateValidApplicationUser()
        {
            ApplicationUser applicationUser = new ApplicationUser();

            applicationUser.UserName = "ValidUser";

            //applicationUser.Password = "ValidPass";

            return applicationUser;
        }

        public ApplicationUser CreateInValidApplicationUser()
        {
            ApplicationUser applicationUser = new ApplicationUser();

            applicationUser.UserName = "InValidUser";

            //applicationUser.Password = "ValidPass";

            return applicationUser;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you investigated using TestServer?  https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/testing/integration-testing.html

Comment: Thanks @Brad, I think this is exactly what I'm looking for. I was just trying too hard to make a unit test out of the problem when it's an implementation concern.

Comment: its possible to mock HttpContext with TypeMock Isolator, example: https://www.typemock.com/docs?book=Isolator&page=Documentation%2FHtmlDocs%2Fsample1fakinghttpcontextandmodelstate.htm

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's pretty much impossible to test with `HttpContext`. It's a sealed class that doesn't utilize any interfaces, so you cannot mock it. Usually, your best bet is to abstract away the code that works with `HttpContext`, and then test just your other, more application-specific code.

It looks like you've sort of already done this via `HttpContextAccessor`, but you're utilizing it incorrectly. First, you're exposing the `HttpContext` instance, which pretty much defeats the entire purpose. This class should be able to return something like `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` on its own, like: `httpContextAccessor.IsAuthenticated`. Internally, the property would access the private `HttpContext` instance and just return the result.

Once you're utilizing it in this way, you can then mock `HttpContextAccessor` to simply return what you need for your tests, and you don't have to worry about supplying it with an `HttpContext` instance.

Granted, this means there's still some untested code, namely, the accessor methods that work with `HttpContext`, but these are generally very straight-forward. For example, the code for `IsAuthenticated` would just be something like `return httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`. The only way you're going to screw that up is if you fat-finger something, but the compiler will warn you about that.

Comment: Would it be correct then to say that testing the Cookie Authentication Middleware can only be achieved as part of integration testing within the context of a running web process; and that the abstraction of HttpContext interactions is the key to unit testing the rest of the code as I think you have suggested?

Comment: Yes. Your unit tests should focus on small discrete "units" of functionality, hence the name. The fact that a cookie has been set is an implementation detail, and shouldn't matter to your test code.

Comment: @ChrisPratt this question is about ASP.NET Core and the OP uses `DefaultHttpContext` which is an implementation of the abstract base class [`HttpContext`](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/1ff417f3216e4fa0eb87e9adacd2379450fae524/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions/HttpContext.cs), which is perfectly possible to mock in a unit test. However, your point about more focussed tests is valid.

Comment: @HenkMollema would that mean mocking `DefaultHttpContext`'s methods that I call, like `ContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`, to act as I would expect? I understand then I could unit test `CookieSessionManager` but would still need integration tests for the Cookie Authentication Middleware?

Comment: @EdwardComeau I guess it's easier to implement `HttpContext` class yourself, just with the parts your interested in.

Answer (score 11):

I created this helper functionality for my unit tests, this allowed me to test those specific methods that required portions of the httpRequest.

```
public static IHttpContextAccessor GetHttpContext(string incomingRequestUrl, string host)
    {
        var context = new DefaultHttpContext();
        context.Request.Path = incomingRequestUrl;
        context.Request.Host = new HostString(host);

        //Do your thing here...

        var obj = new HttpContextAccessor();
        obj.HttpContext = context;
        return obj;
    }
```

Comment: I think this certainly should be highlighted a bit more: in AspNetCore it appears that getting the DefaultHttpContext() and then adding all you would like to it is the right way to go about when unit testing your code to which you would like to supply an instance of HttpContext with some values in it. The defaultHttpContext also gets a defaultHttpRequest gets added to it which you can also similarly embellish. DefaultHttpRequest itself is a sealed class (so it can't directly be instantiated by itself). With Net Core this is clearly the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't directly answer the context of the question but it provides an alternative method to testing and when you start using it makes life so much easier.

There is an integration testing package available for ASP.NET Core and documentation about it can be found here:

https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/testing/integration-testing.html

Enjoy!

Comment: Havent been happy with testserver its expensive to maintain and can misses real http problems ..  now using black box testing and mockserver

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Test class Like below which inherit the HttpContext. And use the test class where you need it. You can add the missing implementation on the code.

```
public class TestHttpContext : HttpContext
{
    [Obsolete]
    public override AuthenticationManager Authentication
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public override ConnectionInfo Connection
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public override IFeatureCollection Features
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public override IDictionary<object, object> Items
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        set { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public override HttpRequest Request
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public override CancellationToken RequestAborted
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        set { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public override IServiceProvider RequestServices
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        set { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    HttpResponse _response;
    public override HttpResponse Response
    {
        get
        {
            if (this._response == null)
            {
                this._response = new TestHttpResponse();
                this._response.StatusCode = 999;
            }

            return this._response;
        }
    }

    public override ISession Session
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        set { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public override string TraceIdentifier
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        set { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public override ClaimsPrincipal User
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        set { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public override WebSocketManager WebSockets
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public override void Abort()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind showing an example of this extended class being used in a test?